# Difference between inclusion and exclusion criteria

Tags: writing, writing-style

Authors frequently report criteria of selecting subjects in studies in two separate categories, *inclusion* and *exclusion criteria*, e.g.:

> Inclusion criteria:
>
> - age between 18-60
> - has the disease x
>
> Exclusion criteria:
>
> - smoker
> - has disease y

Alternatively, one can simply put these criteria under one category:

> Inclusion (or selection) criteria:
>
> - age between 18-60
> - has disease x
> - is **not** smoker
> - does **not** have the disease y

Is there a real distinction between the two terms? Or are they used just as a matter of convention?

Comment: Sorry, but your question seems to be about the content of research, which is off topic for this site. Maybe you could reword and place on the stats SE site or a biology SE site?

Answer (score 1):

In some ways the second is clearer since no one will interpret it as the inclusion criteria overriding the exclusion. Your criteria is *and* for all items. Between 18 - 60 AND ... AND doesn't have disease y.

But in general, if it is clear what you mean it should be fine. Clarity trumps form.